# php string replace/remove

Tags: php, string, replace

Say I have strings: `"Sports Car (45%)"`, or `"Truck (50%)"`, how can I convert them to `"Sports_Car"` and `"Truck"`.

I know about `str_replace` or whatever but how do I clip the brackets and numbers part off the end? That's the part I'm struggling with.

Comment: Do you always have "String (Int%)" ? Use regular expression...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$s = "Sports Car (45%)";
$s = preg_replace(array('/\([^)]*\)/','/^\s*|\s*$/','/ /'),array('','','_'),$s);
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/UarCJ)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options here, but I would do one of these:

```
// str_replace() the spaces to _, and rtrim() numbers/percents/brackets/spaces/underscores
$result = str_replace(' ','_',rtrim($str,'01234567890%() _'));
```

or

```
// Split by spaces, remove the last element and join by underscores
$split = explode(' ',$str);
array_pop($split);
$result = implode('_',$split);
```

or you could use one of a thousand regular expression approaches, as suggested by the other answers.

Deciding which approach to use depends on exactly how your strings are formatted, and how sure you are that the format will always remain the same. The regex approach is potentially more complicated but could afford finer-grained control in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex should be able to achieve that:

```
$str = preg_replace('#\([0-9]+%\)#', '', $str);
```

Of course, you could also choose to use `strstr()` to look for the (

Comment: That returns "Sport" instead of "Sport_Car"

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using explode:

```
<?php
$string = "Sports Car (45%)";
$arr = explode(" (",$string);
$answer = $arr[0];
echo $answer;
?>
```